# Calling a python function from R with passing the arguments

Tags: r, python-3.x

Is there any package for calling a python function from R by passing  the function arguments through R? Now i have directly called the python file using `system` in R.

```
a<-system('/home/anaconda3/bin/python  /home/Desktop/myfile.py' ,intern = TRUE)
```

But this `myfile.py` file is having a function with paramenter. How to specify the parameter in R?

I have tried `system('/home/anaconda3/bin/python  /home/Desktop/myfile.py  argument',wait=FALSE,intern = TRUE)` .But it returns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example I want to pass the number of core that my python script can use:

```
system(paste('/home/anaconda3/bin/python','home/Desktop/myfile.py',NCORE))
```

Then in Python Script before launch the function I can read my parameter in this way:

```
n_core = int(sys.argv[1])
```

sys.argv is a list in Python, which contains the command-line arguments passed to the script.

Comment: I'm attempting this same logic right now, and R is finding the executable but not finding the .py script.  The .py script does exist.  Is there any special difference between ' or "? Should there be spaces between the string objects passed through system()?

Comment: Oh, apparently you can't have spaces in the path name.  It runs if I remove spaces in the underlying folder structure names.  Is there a way to keep spaces?  I can rely on myself to not put spaces in but I can't guarantee that others using this script will do the same.

Answer (score 1):

please look at [reticulate](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate)

```
library(reticulate)
os <- import("os")
os$listdir(".")
```